# how to install thunderbird in Elementary os 0.4.1 (Loki)?

Tags: system-installation, thunderbird

I am using elementary os 0.4.1 Loki, can anyone let me know how to install Thunderbird?

Note: Thunderbird not showing in app center.

Answer (score 1):

It's weird. Thunderbird is showing for me in AppCenter. But if you want to install it manually, open a terminal and type the following commands. You will have to type your password when requested:

```
sudo apt install -y software-properties-common
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:mozillateam/thunderbird-stable 
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install thunderbird
```

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to add a PPA, even if it does not show in the *AppCenter* you can  install it via the command line

```
sudo apt install thunderbird
```

Comment: Due to some bug with a conflict between Gmail and Thunderbird you do have to add the PPA for a gmail account to work with Thunderbird. Although you want the PPA of "sudo add-apt-repository ppa:mozillateam/thunderbird-next" ---hope this helps others who have the issue with Gmail and Thunderbird.